# Python: Appending one text array to another adds a "u"?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

This should be a really easy question to answer for anyone who actually knows how to use Python (obviously that isn't me).  I'm using Python 2.7.9 and I found some example code from this website:

http://pythonicprose.blogspot.com/2010/04/python-tkinter-frontend-example-to-ping.html

But when I run the module the reply text isn't a ping time, it's:

*Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again.*

So I added a few print statements and found that the strings that are supposed to be passed to the command-line are adding a "u" like this:

```
www.google.com

['ping', '-n', '1']
['ping', '-n', '1', u'www.google.com\n']
```

So how does that u get between the '1' and 'www.google.com\n' and how can it be gotten rid of?  I presume it's some sort of escape character but I can't figure out where it's being added in.

```
from Tkinter import *
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()

        # create and position widgets

        self.label = Label(frame, text="Enter IP Address or Server Name:")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.textbox = Text(frame, height=1, width=40)
        self.textbox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        self.textbox.insert(END, "www.google.com")

        self.resultsBox = Text(frame, height=10, width=60)
        self.resultsBox.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Ping",
                               width=10, command=self.doPing)
        self.hi_there.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

    def doPing(self):
        # reset result box
        self.resultsBox.delete(1.0, END)
        # get text

        texttext = self.textbox.get(1.0, END)
        exelist = ['ping', '-n', '1']
        exelist.append(texttext)
        # Execute command (these ping commands are windows specific).
        # In Linux you would use the '-c' to specify count.

        exe = Popen(exelist, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        out, err = exe.communicate()
        while out:
            self.resultsBox.insert(END, out)
            out, err = exe.communicate()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, text indexes are strings, not floats. `1.0` is safe to use, but you should get in the habit of always using strings or eventually you'll get unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "u" just means the string "www.google.com\n" is a Unicode string, it should have no effect on your program at all.

The problem is more likely that you are trying to ping "www.google.com\n" rather than "www.google.com" (note there is a new line in there).

Try stripping the whitespace from your input before attempting to ping it. Ie: `exelist.append(texttext)` becomes `exelist.append(texttext.strip())`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last string is a unicode string based on how you processed it. If you want to make everyone an ASCII string you can use str on all class members:

```
In [1]: a = u'i am unicode'

In [2]: b = 'i am ascii\n'

In [3]: x = [a, b]

In [4]: print x
[u'i am unicode', 'i am ascii\n']

In [5]: print [ str (s) for s in x ]
['i am unicode', 'i am ascii\n']
```

Comment: I'd like to try this but... I'm... not sure... how to implement it... into the code. *[blush]*

Comment: You'd do this by editing the line: 

    exelist.append(str (texttext)), 

or you can take both my and loocid's suggestions and use

    exelist.append(str (texttext).strip ())